# Definition or search of a set.

Tags: logic

I don't understand what the following structure means, someone could explain to me what it consists of: $\langle \Bbb N,\{(n,n+1):n\in\Bbb N\}\rangle$

I put the context of why I want to know what the structure is.

> Find a statement that is true in one of the structures and false in the other.
>
> $a)$ $\langle \Bbb N,<\rangle $ and $\langle \Bbb N,\{(n,n+1):n\in\Bbb N\}\rangle$

Comment: It's a __relation__ on $\mathbb N$, just like "$<$" is. If you were going to assign a symbol to  it, say "$@$", then $x@y$ would mean that $y$ is one more than $x$, which might also be described as "$y$ is the successor to $x$".

Comment: It is the collection of pairs: $\{ (0,1), (1,2), (2,3), \ldots \}$

Comment: In fact it's the graph of the successor *function*. A first-order formula can express that a binary relation $R$ is a function.